# nagios -- different options for different contacts?

Tags: nagios

I have two sets of on-call people -- sysadmins and operators.  I have nagios monitoring an SSH service.  If the service goes down or comes back up, I want to notify the operators; they don't need WARNING or FLAPPING, just CRITICAL and OK.  But I want to notify the sysadmins for everything.

As far as I can see, the only way to do that is to create two entirely separate nagios services, perhaps called SSH and SSH2, both running the same check.  They would be treated entirely separately by nagios and listed separately in the nagios web pages.

Can I do this with a single service -- set up two different contacts with two different `notification_options` values ?  I've tried a few times, but as far as I can tell, redefining a service just replaces the old configuration with the new one.

(I may have the same question about hosts, too.  And I **definitely** don't to have duplicate hosts in my nagios web pages.)

Comment: Each [service definition](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#service) can take multiple contacts. Each [contact](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#contact) can have its own values for service_notification_options. You generally have to reload or restart Nagios after making changes.

Comment: Thank you ... but I don't (at this time) want to change my defaults.  I'm trying to change one specific service on one specific host.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "my defaults". You can change the service definition to use two contacts; you can change the value of service_notification_options for each contact; you can create a new contact for SSH operators or for SSH sysadmins. If you don't want to change any of those things, you're going to have trouble. Consider putting all these Nagios files under version control.

Comment: My understanding, when you said "each contact can have its own values for service_notification_options", you meant that I would be adjusting the service notification options for that contact for ALL services.  I don't want to change the default service notification options for this contact. I want to change the specific service notification options for this specific service when it alerts this specific contact.  But the "create new contacts" idea might be the one i need.

Answer (score 0):

*Default* is a fuzzy term when we're talking about Nagios.

Assuming that

- the sysadmin contact has a "standard" set of notification options (say, w,u,c), and
- the sysadmins need a different set of notification options for SSH ("everything": w,u,c,r,f,s,n)

then I think you just need to create another contact for sysadmins. Name it, say, sysadmin_ssh. Set its notification options to w,u,c,r,f,s,n. Then use *that* contact for the SSH service, and the standard sysadmin contact for all the other services.

Also, version control is your friend. VC makes testing safe and painless.

Comment: *sigh* For internal reasons related to my specific setup, I cannot create a separate contact. The `contact_name` must be set to a specific value.  Although this is probably the correct answer in general, it will not work for me.

Comment: @hymie: Maybe we need to attack this from the other direction. What *can* you change? (Edit your question; include these new restrictions.)